# How to remove sidenote citations in Tufte-LaTeX

Tags: bibliographies, tufte

In Tufte-LaTeX, the standard behavior of the `\cite` command is to put the reference in the sidenotes area (see example at https://github.com/Tufte-LaTeX/tufte-latex/blob/master/sample-handout.pdf). Additionally, they will appear in the bibliography.

I want to have the standard citation behavior without the reference appearing in the sitenotes.

I've messed around with the `tufte-common.def` file, but could not get the desired effect. Can anybody give me a hint on how to achieve this?

Comment: Use the `nobib` option: `\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-book}`. Then you can `\usepackage{natbib}` or `\usepackage{biblatex}` or whatever you like.

Comment: @godbyk: Nope, that doesn't work. It's still in the margins. Besides that, the compiler complains about `\bibhang` already defined

Comment: @ChristianHupfer For me it works as intended, both in my own project as well as in the minimal example provided by you.

Comment: @godbyk Please provide the comment as answer so I can close this question.

Comment: @PaulKlemm: The `nobib` option is not documented in the manual. Apparently, I've missing some knowledge here, so its better to delete my answer

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Ok, your call. I personally like to have different potential solutions on StackExchange questions, because most often they have different caveats. Maybe your solution had advantages over the `nobib` option, I have not enough knowledge about LaTeX to tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable Tufte-LaTeX's handling of citations, you can pass the `nobib` option to the document class:

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-handout}% or tufte-book
```

You would then need to load the `natbib`, `biblatex`, or other bibliography package yourself with, e.g., `\usepackage{natbib}`.

The `\cite` command will behave the same as it does for the `article` or `book` document class.

Comment: The `nobib` approach did not work for me, using the `tufte-handout` style in overleaf. Instead, I edited the `tufte-common.def` file by commenting out line 907: `\let\cite\@tufte@normal@cite`.